# 'str' object not callable error How do I make my classes overload?

Tags: python, inheritance, overloading

I am trying to overload my operators in this class I made. I made this plant class and I am trying to print it out. I am still pretty new to this so my understanding probably isn't the best but any help you can provide will be amazing. Here is my mmain.py:

```
import Fungi_
import Animal
import inheritance
import Monera
import Plant

grass = Plant.Ferns("Good", "large")
print(grass.scent() + grass.size())
```

Here is my class and subclasses,

```
from inheritance_assignment import living_thing

class Plant(living_thing):
    def __init__(self, type):
        self.type = type

class Equiseta(Plant):
    def __init__(self, type, color):
        self.type = type
        self.color = color

class Lycopodia(Plant):
    def __init__(self, color, size):
        self.color = color
        self.size = size

class Gymnosperms(Plant):
    def __init__(self, size, color):
        self.size = size
        self.color = color

class Anginosperm(Plant):
    def __init__(self, length, color):
        self.length = length
        self.color = color

class Ferns(Plant):
    def __init__(self, scent, size):
        self.scent = scent
        self.size = size

class Mosses(Plant):
    def __init__(self, wetness, size):
        self.wetness = wetness
        self.size = size
```

Here is the error it gives me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 8, in <module>
    print(grass.scent() + grass.size())
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Any Information will be grand! Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error message is quite clear. Why are you trying to call `grass.scent` and `grass.size`?

Answer (score 0):

Classes in python have methods (functions) and attributes (variables).  In your `Ferns` class you defined `size` and `scent` as attributes, but you are attempting to access them in the `print` statement as if they are methods by appending `()` to their names.  Assuming you want to concatenate the strings associated with `scent` and `size` then this syntax should work:

```
print(grass.scent + grass.size)
```

```
Goodlarge
```